# Consistency checking the relation between total differentials using the Jacobian matrix

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian

I have the following relationship between variables:
$$\varepsilon = \Psi -\frac{v^2}{2}\tag{1}$$

A while back, I had an integral with respect to $v$ and I wanted to convert it to an integral with respect to $\varepsilon$. I used the Jacobian method of converting differential elements.

1. $$\mathrm{d}v = \det\left[\frac{\partial v}{\partial \varepsilon}\right]\mathrm{d}\varepsilon$$
   $$\frac{\partial \varepsilon}{\partial v} = -v \implies \frac{\partial v}{\partial \varepsilon} = -\frac{1}{v} \implies \mathrm{d}v = -\frac{1}{v}\mathrm{d}\varepsilon$$
   $$\implies \mathrm{d}\varepsilon = -v\mathrm{d}v\tag{2}$$

I was satisfied with equation (2) and used it to prove an expression in a research paper. Now, I wonder what would have happened if I need to change $\mathrm{d}\varepsilon$ to $\mathrm{d}\Psi$. In such a case,

2. $$\mathrm{d}\varepsilon = \det\left[\frac{\partial \varepsilon}{\partial \Psi}\right]\mathrm{d}\Psi$$
   $$\frac{\partial \varepsilon}{\partial \Psi} = 1$$
   $$\implies \mathrm{d}\varepsilon = \mathrm{d}\Psi\tag{3}$$

Then, the prediction for the relationship between $\mathrm{d}v$ and $\mathrm{d}\Psi$ from eqn (2) and eqn (3) would be:
$$-v\mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{d}\varepsilon = \mathrm{d}\Psi$$
$$\text{i.e.,}\ \ \  \ \ \  -v\mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{d}\Psi\tag{4}$$

However, if I directly use the Jacobian method to find out the relation between $\mathrm{d}v$ and $\mathrm{d}\Psi$,

3. $$\mathrm{d}\Psi = \det\left[\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial v}\right]\mathrm{d}v$$
   $$\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial v} = v$$
   $$\implies \mathrm{d}\Psi = v\mathrm{d}v\tag{5}$$

Clearly, eqn (4) and eqn (5) don't match. So, there is some inconsistency here in the way I am relating the differentials. Could someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong, because I was able to prove the expression in the research paper using eqn (2).

Comment: Your inconsistencies arise from treating certain quantities as constants with respect to others in *some* calculations but not in others. This amounts to treating a partial derivative as $0$ which may not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that all quantities depend on each other. This amounts to *not* making the assumption that any partial derivatives are $0$. Since you seem interested in the differential $\mathrm{d}\Psi$, first solve for $\Psi$:
$$
\Psi = \varepsilon + \frac{v^2}{2}
$$
Now, use the (multivariable) chain rule:
$$
\mathrm{d}\Psi 
= \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial\varepsilon}\, \mathrm{d}\varepsilon
+ \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial v}\, \mathrm{d}v 
= 1\, \mathrm{d}\varepsilon
+ v\, \mathrm{d}v
$$
Your various formulas arise from assuming certain partial derivatives vanish. For $(2)$, (perhaps without realizing it) you assume that $\mathrm{d}\Psi = 0$, so $\mathrm{d}\varepsilon = -v\, \mathrm{d}v$. For $(3)$, you assume that $\mathrm{d}v = 0$, so $\mathrm{d}\Psi = \mathrm{d}\varepsilon$, etc.

Once you assume that more than one of these differentials vanish, then they all vanish, so your equations amount to the tautology $0 = 0$, which is of course equivalent to $0 = -0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About the assumption that all quantities depend on each other, the degree of freedom resides in choosing a value of $\Psi$. Choosing a particular value of $\Psi$, fixes the probability distribution function for $v$. Then, once $v$ is sampled from the probability distribution function, $\varepsilon$ is computed using equation (1). In such a probabilistic situation, can you still assume that all the partial derivatives are non-zero?